# Unknown turkish character in solr core

Tags: solr

I have a solr core which includes many data. I realize some datas has turkish character issue in my solr core. Here is the issued data in this below solr query

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"ID:406768",
      "fl":"DocName"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "DocName":"Motor Teslim D�k�manlar� Listesi"}]
  }}
```

I'm defining my solr field **DocName** like this in my schema.xml

```
<field name="DocName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

How can I fix this issue?

I was using simpleposttool for indexing data to solr. I was using below code in cmd.

```
java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/update -jar post.jar TableArchive.csv
```

Comment: Seems like the content hasn't been indexed as UTF-8 or isn't being displayed as UTF-8?

Comment: @MatsLindh How can I index the content as UTF-8 admin panel or how can I update the indexed data ? Any suggestiion?

Comment: How are you indexing your data now? How are you inserting data into Solr? What is the original term that you've indexed? Have you check that the data you're inserting is actually correct? Documents will be updated when a document with the same id is being sent to Solr; the old one is then overwritten with the new one.

Comment: @MatsLindh Firstly I was indexing data with simpleposttool but now I'm using Solr's admin panel and I'm inserting data as XML. My data is correct but there is no option that I can set UTF-8 in solr's admin panel.

Comment: If it's correctly encoded on the way in, it should be correct on the way out. Is your result directly from the query page in Solr's Admin?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, it's from solr's query page and thank you for your support. I tried to add data in solr's admin page with overwrite option. It's coming correctly right now.

Comment: Then you're sending it to Solr with the wrong encoding - i.e. it's being picked up the wrong way when you're indexing it. How are you sending content to Solr? Add details information to your question.

Comment: @MatsLindh I added details of sending content to Solr. Thanks.

Comment: In that case try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` where you replace `UTF8` with the actual encoding used in the file. You may try `iso-8859-9` which is the "old" charset used for Turkish characters. Another option is `Windows-1254` / `cp1254` which is the Window charset commonly used for Turkish.